# How do I allow other users of my application to access RDS from their computer?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, pymysql

I am creating an inventory application for my company. The app has it's inventory information stored through RDS. I am using MySQL and have pymysql to connect. Throughout development I have had no issue connecting from the laptop that I created the database from. I want to know how to allow other computers with the application to connect. Is there a way to avoid adding each individual IP address to a security group? I would just like those with the application downloaded to have access without requiring additional login credentials.

When I use the application on my home computer I receive an error when trying to connect to the database.

```
pymysql.connect(db=dbname, host=host, port=port, user=user, password=password)
```

[image]

Comment: Worth reading https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/Security/Security_Database_Services_Whitepaper.pdf. I think you should require SSL for all connections and then whitelist source IPs, if you must expose the database to the internet.

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: When you say it "works fine on my laptop", I presume you are using it from a work network? What happens if you take the laptop home and try it from there? Try to identify whether the issue is related to from _where_ you are accessing, or from _which_ computer. What is the error you receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Side-note on security:

It is typically a **very bad idea to grant remote applications direct access to your database**, especially without giving each user/app their own password.

You are effectively opening your database to anyone that has the credentials, and you are including those credentials in the app itself. Somebody could obtain those credentials and, presumably, do quite a bit of damage to the contents of the database.

Also, you are **locking-in your database schema** with the inability to change in future. Let's say you have a table with particular columns and your application directly access that table. In future, if you modify the table, you should need to simultaneously update *every application that is using the database*. That's not really feasible if other people are running the application on their own systems.

The better approach is to **expose an API** and have the applications use the API to access the data:

- The API should manage **authentication**, so you can determine who to allow in and, more importantly, track who is doing what. This will also avoid the problem of having to add each individual IP address of users, since you will be managing an authentication layer.
- The API will apply a layer of **business logic** rather than allowing the remote application to do whatever it wishes. This stops remote users being able to do things like deleting the entire database. It also means that, instead of remote apps simply passing an SQL statement, they will need to pass information through the defined API (typically in the form of Action + Parameters).
- It provides a **stable interface** into the application allowing you to make changes in the backend (eg changing the contents of a table) while still presenting the same interface to client applications.

**Rule of thumb:** Only one application server should be directly accessing a given database. You might have multiple servers running the same software to provide high availability and to support a high load of traffic, but don't let the client apps directly access the database. That's what makes a "3-tier" application so much better than a "2-tier" application.  (`Client - Server - Database`)

Comment: Could you go into a little more detail about "exposing an API"? I am teaching myself programming and understand what API's are, but have no experience creating/writing them. This application is going to be a small inventory database that will only be used by a maximum of 5 people within the small company; if that makes any difference.

Comment: The application is also not web-based. It is a standalone computer application built with tkinter.

Comment: I have also added an image of one of the windows from the application. The buttons on the side and within the toplevel window call methods that open connections to the database, make changes and then close the connection.

Comment: Being a Python program, your users would (presumably) have access to the application code and would be able to see how to interact with the database. They could then _run any database command they wish_, including viewing and deleting other people's data. This is because there is no "business logic" layer to check what they are doing. See: [3-Tier Architecture: A Complete Overview - JReport](https://www.jinfonet.com/resources/bi-defined/3-tier-architecture-complete-overview/) and [What is N-Tier Architecture? Examples, Tutorials & More](https://stackify.com/n-tier-architecture/).

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look when I get the chance.